# Google drive API error invalid_grant after 10 days

Tags: google-drive-api

Every time the error "invalid_grant" appears after 10 days of work. The error can be corrected by replacing the token. Tell me why the token only works for 10 days?[image]

Comment: Consider providing the rest of the code corresponding to the authorization process, and please provide the code in text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid grant is normally caused by the token have expired.

Assuming that you are using a refresh token if the user has revoked your access then the refresh token will no longer work and you will get an invalid grant error. You should request that the user authorize your application again.

If your application is still in testing phase and has not yet been verified by google refresh tokens are only valid for about 7 -14 days after that the users access will automatically be revoked and your refresh token will no longer work.  You will need to have the test user authorize your application again.

If your refresh token has not been used in six months then it will also be automatically revoked. and you will need to have the user authorize your application again.

If the refresh token was created with one of the gmail scopes and the user changes their password. then the refresh token will also be revoked and you will need to have the user authorize your application again.

[Apps with access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en)